# PHP string comparison VIEW DIFF PEAR

Tags: php, string, pear

I am trying to compare two strings, and I want to know if something from string 1 is deleted or replaced in string 2.

I tried using the following:
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.text.text-diff.intro.php
http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php

But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you find that?
http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4189

Answer (score 0):

Is http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.text.text-diff.usage-examples.shell.php not enough?

If you installed the Text_Diff package, you will also have an example installed automatically:

```
$ pear list-files text_diff|grep doc
doc  /usr/share/php/docs/Text_Diff/docs/examples/1.txt
doc  /usr/share/php/docs/Text_Diff/docs/examples/2.txt
doc  /usr/share/php/docs/Text_Diff/docs/examples/diff.php
```